# Jade/Pug - Extending layout - variable not being recognised

Tags: html, node.js, pug, template-engine

I am using Jade/Pug to simplify my HTML and I'm trying to create a block with meta details. When I extend my layout in my index file I can't seem to replace **#{desc}** with the **desc** variable.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Layout:**

```
doctype
html
  head
    block title
        title variables
        meta(name='description' content='#{desc}')
  body
    p hello
```

**Index:**

```
extends includes/layout
block title
    title things
    - var desc="hello"
```

The meta isn't being outputted when the source code is viewed

Answer (score 4):

Jade/Pug doesn't *merge* blocks or their scope, which is what you appear to be expecting here. It can only **replace, append or prepend**.

The `block` in `index.pug` is overriding the *default content* in `layout.pug`. `var desc = 'hello'` is never used.

My advice would be define and use a `mixin`, or try to declare your vars outside the scope of the block.

---

```
// layout.pug
doctype
html
  head
    title=title || 'Default Title'
    meta(name='description' content='#{description || "Default desc"}')
  body
    p hello

// index.pug
extends includes/layout
-
    var title = 'Mario'
    var description = 'Luigi'

// <your markup here>
```

Comment: Can append/prepend be used to do what I need in any way - or will I need to go down the **Mixins** route?

Comment: Append or prepend won't merge your variable scope. It simply renders B before or after A.

Comment: See my edit on how you can get what you want without over-complicating with blocks or mixins

Answer (score 4):

Made a bunch of fixes described below.

**layout.pug**

```
- var desc = 'default meta desc'
block variables
doctype
html
  head
    block title
      meta(name='description' content=desc)
  body
    p hello
```

**index.pug**

```
extends includes/layout
block variables
  - desc = "hello"
block append title
  title things
```

- use `block append` instead of `block` for the title
- put variables in the layout and override them in the page
- Reference `desc` directly without the interpolation syntax